# GnuTLS error -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated. (IIS FTP Server)

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019

I have an FTP Site running on IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019. It's been working fine until yesterday.

I started getting the following error while trying to list the directory on Filezilla

GnuTLS error -110: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

I've not seen any viable solution online.

[image]

The server was setup to Require SSL